# Is a piece hanging if it is defended by a higher value piece?

Tags: tactics, patterns

In this extreme examplethe c5 pawn is defended three times, though white can take the pawn with an advantage.

```
 [FEN "2r1k3/2r5/2q5/2p5/8/8/PPR5/KN4B1 w - - 0 1"]
```

What about if the defender is a higher value piece than the attackers, even though it's defended and attacked twice? Clearly, White can take the pawn with an advantage.

```
 [FEN "8/8/3k4/2p2q2/8/8/PPR5/KN4B1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Now it's not hanging:

```
 [FEN "8/8/3k4/2p2r2/8/8/PPR5/KN4B1 w - - 0 1"]
```

What do you call these type of situations if it's not hanging piece?

This position also has a hanging piece:

```
[FEN "2b4k/3q2pp/8/5p2/8/2B1N3/PP6/KN4Q1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would still be called a hanging piece. **If the piece can be taken with impunity**, it is a hanging piece. It is irrelevant how many attackers there are on the piece, how many defenders there are on the piece, or the point value of the attackers/defenders.

Comment: So you can only determine a hanging piece by calculating into the position and making sure it's safe to take?

Comment: Correct. Very often there is a tactic that allows you to take an otherwise well-defended piece. People still say that the opponent hung a piece due to some tactic. This only gets complicated when the tactics are extremely complicated.

Comment: So a tactic is not really a tactic if it doesn't work.